# how to compare SQL dates with null

Tags: sql

I want to count the number of rows having date is null.i tried following

```
SELECT R.COUNTRY_CD,COUNT(R.EFFECTIVE_END_DT) AS d_null
FROM REIMBURSEMENT R
GROUP BY R.COUNTRY_CD,R.EFFECTIVE_END_DT
HAVING R.COUNTRY_CD = @COUNTRY_CD AND R.EFFECTIVE_END_DT IS NULL
```

but it's giving d_null as 0...

how can i compare a date for `NULL`

Comment: It seems you're looking for `COUNT(IF(R.EFFECTIVE_END_DT IS NULL, 1, NULL)) AS d_null`

Comment: How would the COUNT(Column) give NULL? Either its zero or more?!

Comment: yup,it's giving 0 though their are multiple records

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`COUNT` only counts non-`NULL` entries.

Try `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)` instead of `COUNT(R.EFFECTIVE_END_DT)`.

Since you provide a `Country_CD` as parameter, and you only want `NULL` dates, you can probably simplify your query to:

```
SELECT R.Country_CD, COUNT(*) AS d_null
FROM Reimbursement R
WHERE R.Country_CD = @Country_CD AND R.Effective_End_DT IS NULL
```

Comment: but i want to get the total count of null dates

Comment: @RohanS `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)` will return the count of `NULL` dates because of the `GROUP BY` and `R.EFFECTIVE_END_DT IS NULL` in the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT R.COUNTRY_CD,COUNT(R.EFFECTIVE_END_DT) AS d_null
FROM REIMBURSEMENT R
GROUP BY R.COUNTRY_CD,R.EFFECTIVE_END_DT
HAVING R.COUNTRY_CD = @COUNTRY_CD AND DATE_FORMAT(R.EFFECTIVE_END_DT,"%y") IS NULL
```